# How to work with shimming, third-party scripts, and interdependencies

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm new to working with RequireJS, and am trying to figure out shimming 3rd-party, interdependent scripts. Specifically, I'm trying to get the [Stanford Crypto](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/) scripts imported.

Basically, the suite is comprised of the core (jsbn.js, jsbn2.js, base64.js, rng.js, and prng4.js), a basic RSA script (rsa.js), and an extended RSA script (rsa2.js).

rsa.js defines the global variable-object `RSAKey`, and rsa2.js references it.

```
function RSAKey() {
  this.n = null;
  this.e = 0;
  this.d = null;
  this.p = null;
  this.q = null;
  this.dmp1 = null;
  this.dmq1 = null;
  this.coeff = null;
}
```

I've set up my shim in a way that I thought was correct, but I get the error "RSAKey is not defined" in rsa2.js. The following is my shim:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jsbn': "../StanfordRSA/jsbn.js",
        'jsbn2': "../StanfordRSA/jsbn2.js",
        'base64': "../StanfordRSA/base64.js",
        'rng': "../StanfordRSA/rng.js",
        'prng4': "../StanfordRSA/prng4.js",
        'rsa': "../StanfordRSA/rsa.js",
        'rsa2': "../StanfordRSA/rsa2.js"
    },
    shim: {
        'rsa': {
            deps: ['jsbn', 'jsbn2', 'base64', 'rng', 'prng4'],
            exports: "RSAKey"
        },
        'rsa2': {
            deps: ['rsa']
        }
    }
});
```

My understanding, then, is that if I set 'rsa2' as a requirement in one of my RequireJS modules, it would look at the shim and see that rsa2 is dependent on rsa, which is dependent on the core and exports RSAKey...But that's not what's happening, and it seems like either rsa isn't loading, or it isn't loading correctly. (Please note that all of this works using raw script tags. I'm trying to convert an already existing, already functioning webapp to RequireJS)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic setup is correct, except for 2 things:

1. (really important!) You have to omit the `.js` extensions!!!
2. You probably have missed the *exact* dependencies between the scripts.

After some experimentation and reading the comments at the top of the scripts, the working configuration is:

```
  require.config({
    paths: {
        'jsbn': "../StanfordRSA/jsbn",
        'jsbn2': "../StanfordRSA/jsbn2",
        'base64': "../StanfordRSA/base64",
        'rng': "../StanfordRSA/rng",
        'prng4': "../StanfordRSA/prng4",
        'rsa': "../StanfordRSA/rsa",
        'rsa2': "../StanfordRSA/rsa2"
    },
    shim: {
        'rng': {
          deps: ['prng4']
        },
        'jsbn2': {
          deps: ['jsbn']
        },
        'rsa': {
            deps: ['jsbn', 'rng'],
            exports: 'RSAKey'
        },
        'rsa2': {
            deps: ['rsa', 'jsbn2'],
            exports: 'RSAKey'
        }
    }
  });
```

Check out a plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/lwqIqeHbY9verrgu7wUa?p=preview).

Comment: Got it! Found a few other bugs lurking in my code too, but once I resolved those, the script is loading now! Thanks!